# rails sending bulk mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, bulk-mail

We are using Rails 2.3.8 version. In our application, we tend to send individual email to all users ( around 1500 users - Bulk email ). We are not using any services other than Actionmailer. Hence, **we cannot use any service (like mailGun, sendGrid, mailchimp, etc)**  Also, we have our own SMTP server, through which all the mails are sent.

We have added our mailing functionality to be executed in two scenarios.

1. Rake Task with CRON JOB ( Auto mails to be sent at specific time)
2. Via controller ( Mails are sent when a button is clicked)

In both the cases, Initially, the mails are forwarded to the users without any issues. As the user count increases, suddenly the mail functionality stops and throws either of the two following errors.

1. 535 5.7.3 Authentication Unsuccessful
2. Execution expired

Could anyone please help me sort out the issue?

Is there any timeout value that has to be set for SMTP server connectivity? Or are there any restrictions (like number of mails sent per minute) ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It sounds like these issues are caused by your SMTP server.  Usually there are restrictions on mails that can be sent, and if you are sending them from a gmail address for example, then google might also step in if you send too many, flagging them as spam (i have received 24 hour bans from google before for testing mass emailing through my gmail account!).  Usually you would configure actionmailer to send eg 200 every minute or something.

Comment: Thanks Max for your reply. But 1500 mails does not seem to be too many.    Because large amount of mails ( around 10000 or more) could be sent from Rails applications. Sending 1500 mails from our application takes a very long time ( nearly 1 hour for 350 mails).

Comment: It doesn't matter how many emails someone else is sending from their rails application, and whether you think it "isn't too many".  What matters is your SMTP server config.  For all you know, it may be set up with a limit which is not adequate for your needs.  I suggest you investigate this rather than dismiss it as not being possible.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you should seriously consider mandrillapp.com. Makes life so much simpler and you may fit into their free plan with that volume.